# Chipgroup margin and multilines

Tags: android, android-layout, android-chips

I'm developing an app with chips.

I have a constraint layout with a TextView and a ChipGroup. The chips are added programmatically.

This is the layout

```
...
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:gravity="end"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chartView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/project3">

</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:text="Pippo"
    android:textColor="@color/greenPositive"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chartView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/project3" />
...
```

The activity appears as the screenshot (I have put a red background in the chipgroup to show the area)

[image]

- The ChipGroup is constrainted to the end of textview, but ignore this constraint and the margin.
- At the end a Chip is truncated, but the ChipGroup has a 16dp of margin at the end.
- The first and second row are not aligned with the first row
- I put gravity end in the ChipGroup, but the chips are aligned to start.

How to solve all these problems?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 6):

Adding `app:chipSpacingVertical` attribute to ChipGroup View will solve this.

```
 <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipSpacingVertical="4dp"/>
```

Comment: It is not working on my case

Answer (score 0):

You can add to chipgroup in layout chip and make it invisible it will be as margin than you can add what you want programmatically

Comment: Answer is unclear
As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).